# unable to view Nintex Workflow 2013 menu->Task Delegation option

Tags: nintex-workflow

I'm using Nintex 2013.

I need to use Task Delegation functionality.but I'm unable to find that option under Click on my name at the top right of the screen.

**below image show my screen.**

[image]

**I need below option**

[image]

other wise if there is any alternate option available to use Task Delegation with out Flexi task

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look in Central Admin for SharePoint, under **allowed actions** for nintex, and ensure the **allow delegation** is checked.

Hope this helps